# How to get full Value Name from registry with spaces using Batch Script?

Tags: batch-file

I have some entries in registry. E.g:

```
ValueName          ValueData
a b c.exe            True
abc.exe              False
etc.
```

My trial:

```
@echo off 
set key=path to reg. key
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('reg query "%key%" /v "*.exe"') do (
echo Value Name: %%a
echo Value Data: %%b
)
pause
```

Using above code, i am not getting desired output because of spaces:

```
Value Name: a
Value Data: REG_SZ
Value Name: abc.exe
Value Data: False
```

output should be full value name with space or any symbol and value data as below example:

```
Value Name: a b c.exe
Value Data: True
Value Name: abc.exe
Value Data: False
```

As above example, we have value name in registry with spaces also. So using my trails, i am unable to get my desired output using batch file scripting.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These are required only for the demonstration

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76951819.txt"

ECHO method 1
FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 SET "name=!line:~0,21!"
 CALL :trim name
 ECHO Value name : !name!
 ECHO Value data : !line:~21!
)

ECHO method 2
FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 SET "data=!line:*  =!"
 CALL SET "line=%%line:  !data!=%%"
 CALL :trim line
 CALL :trim data
 ECHO Value name : !line!
 ECHO Value data : !data!
)

GOTO :EOF

:: remove leading and trailing spaces from variable %1

:trim
IF "!%1!"=="" GOTO :eof
IF "!%1:~-1!"==" " SET "%1=!%1:~0,-1!"&GOTO trim
IF "!%1:~0,1!"==" " SET "%1=!%1:~1!"&GOTO trim
GOTO :eof
```

Notes: 
I have used a file containing your posted example data for demonstration purposes. The line(s)

```
FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
```

should be replaced by

```
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%e IN ('reg query "%key%" /v "*.exe"') DO (
```

to process the `reg query` command directly.

In the first method, the key value is `21`. Since your posted data has the second column starting in column 20 and 22, `21` may need to be adjusted. Siply assign the required line to the variable `line` and split `line` into the first 21 characters and the remainder. Trim the result and display.

In the second, assign the part following the first 2 consecutive spaces to `data`, and the part up to the first 2 consecutive spaces to `line`, trim and show.

The `trim` subroutine simply detects whether the first or last character is a space, removes it, rinse and repeat.

Note that both the main routine and the subroutine rely on `delayedexpansion`.